# Cast array to Array of Type Message

Tags: angular, typescript

I am receiving the following from an API response in Angular

```
(response) => {

  let messages: Message[] = response.messages;

  for (let message: Message in messages) {

    let description = message.description;

  }
```

But in `let description = message.description;` I get the error:

```
Property 'description' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Is this because I am using a class instead of an interface?

Should message be considered of type Message in my code?

The response is something like:

```
[
  { description: "Some description", type: "1029BA" },
  { description: "Other description", type: "20sdBC" }
]
```

And Message is a class.

```
export class Message {

  description: string;
  type: string;

  constructor(description: string, type?: string) {
    this.description = description;
    this.type = type;
  }    

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your for-in loop to a for-of loop, as yo are looping over the *keys* and not the *values* in the array:

```
for (let message of messages) {

  let description = message.description;

}
```

Comment: I tried that and got the error message "The left-hand side of a 'for...of' statement cannot use a type annotation."

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, I updated the answer. Just remove the type annotation as it by definition always will be of type Message